# How to develop a GridView with a column filled with Text Boxes

Tags: asp.net, gridview, jqgrid, textbox

I have a GridView with 5 fields in jqQrid

```
<cc1:JQGrid ID="Qgrid" runat="server" Width="700px"  Height="100%"
            ondatarequesting="QgridDataRequesting" 
            onrowediting="QgridRowEditing">
         <Columns>
            <trirand:JQGridColumn Searchable="true" 
            SearchToolBarOperation="IsEqualTo" DataType="Int" 
            HeaderText="Order ID" PrimaryKey="True" ></trirand:JQGridColumn>
            <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField='id'   Visible="False"/>
            <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField='last_name'  Visible="False"/>
            <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField='first_name' Visible="False"/>
            <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="opinion" Editable="True" />

        </Columns> 

        <EditInlineCellSettings Enabled="True" />
        <PagerSettings NoRowsMessage="No data in grid." />
        <ToolBarSettings ShowEditButton="true" ShowRefreshButton="True" />
</cc1:JQGrid>
```

I wrote logic for events gridDataRequesting  and gridRowEditing and now my license has expired

I want to write a simple gridview, but I don't know how to add a column with textbox's.

After leaving a textbox I want to I call "function grid RowEditing" (which executes a sql updating with the value from textbox)

**Do you know any free plugin nearly like JqGrid?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to editing the items in the gridview using text boxes, then you can check out this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx). Here edit links are present that helps you in editing rows inline. The grid needs to be associated with an UpdateCommand. In your case that would execute the sql update. An alternative to gridRowEditing.

As for populating the data in the gridview, it can be done in the page load event of the aspx page. A possible alternative to gridDataRequesting in jqGrid.